# Should acronyms be pluralized in navigation menu?

Tags: copywriting

Should sidebar menu navigation links be pluralized if the item is an acronym?

e.g.  for a page where the user can manage a list of Local Area Networks / Wide Area Networks:

**LANs, WANs**
vs
**LAN, WAN**

I feel that the lowercase 's' looks unsightly as a link. Are there conventions for this sort of microcopy?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, you can pluralize the acronyms.** It is ubiquitous, e.g.

- `VIPs` **V**ery **I**mportant **P**erson**s**
- `ATMs` **A**utomated **T**eller **M**achine**s**
- `CPUs` **C**entral **P**rocessing **U**nit**s**

The plural WANs is also used in the [Wikipedia article on WAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network#design_options).

Another interesting question is: **Should we use an apostrophe?** In your case, this could be LANs/WANs or LAN's/WAN's. While there seems to be [no official rules to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym#Representing_plurals_and_possessives), the **common way** of writing seems to be **without apostrophes**.

Comment: Indeed, apostrophes are generally considered a mistake here (though a few style guides license them).

Comment: I agree they can be pluralized, but would also suggest that they *should* be pluralized if the page can deal with more than one. In other words, if the page only supported settings for a single LAN/WAN, then the acronym should stay singular, however if there is support for managing multiple LANs/WANs (like in OPs situation), then the acronyms should be pluralized. Doing so hints to the user that the page manages a list structure.

Comment: @maxathousand Would think so, too +1